# If inside try catch which is inside while loop NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

Why this code throws an exception when I input value more then it is inside if used.

The exception message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

My Code:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choose = in.nextInt();
        in.close();
        if (choose == 1 || choose == 2 || choose == 3) {
            return choose;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("else text");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("exception text");
    }
```

Comment: Presumably because the next token it reads from `in` isn't an `int`. Impossible to say without more information. (I was thinking it would be whitespace, but the `Scanner` docs say whitespace is the default delimiter, so presumably it wouldn't be that...)

Comment: *"...when i input value more then it is inside if used."* Huh?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think when input is not 1,2 and 3 I run his code in http://ideone.com/4lRySS you could go there and test it. he is right and I cant figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close `System.in` you can't re-open it. Remove the `close()` call to fix that. Also you can move the `Scanner` object outsite the loop. No need to create that in every iteration.

```
final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
  try {
    int choose = in.nextInt();
    if (choose == 1 || choose == 2 || choose == 3) {
      return choose;
    } else {
      System.out.println("else text");
    }
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("exception text");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner.close()` contains this little snippet (my bold):

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then **if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked.**

Since `System.in` is of type `InputStream` and therefore implements `Closeable`, closing the scanner *also* closes the underlying standard input stream.

Then, the next time you try to create a scanner using `System.in`, the latter will have already been closed. _That's why you're getting the exception.

You would be better off creating the scanner *once* outside the loop, then just reading values without closing, using something like `nextLine()` if you want to skip input that's not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `in.close();` and it will work.